# Cypher: implement EXISTS sub query functionality with a CALL sub query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

suppose I have a match: `MATCH (from: FromLabel)-[:REL_LABEL]-(to: ToLabel)`

I want to be able to filter out `from` nodes based on whether a path to a specific `OtherLabel` nodes exists AND based on some additional conditions and possible matches or aggregations. Something like that:

```
MATCH (from: FromLabel)-[:REL_LABEL]-(to: ToLabel)
WHERE EXISTS {
MATCH (from: FromLabel)-[:OTHER_REL_LABEL]-(other: OtherLabel)
WHERE other.some_prop = 'value'
WITH from, SUM(other.another_prop) as aggregation_by_from
// ** here goes some more possible match where based on other
}
```

But I simply can't since EXISTS{...} only takes a single `MATCH(...) WHERE(...)` clause (with optional EXISTS nesting of course)

**Question** how can I implement a richer Exists functionality with  CALL sub query?

Comment: In you example, where is the call subquery? Can you give us sample data to work on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually:

With two nested CALL subqueries, I can simulate the functionality of a boolean predicate, for every `from` node. Mind that the inner `CALL` expression uses `UNION`, thus it always returns `FALSE`. When the inner `MATCH...WHERE...<ANYTHING>` `CALL` subquery is evaluated as well and executes `RETURN TRUE AS predicate LIMIT 1` - it will return both `TRUE, FALSE` rows for that given `from` node.

Therefore, we need the outer `CALL` for the sole purpose of filtering out the most appropriate solution:

1. if only `RETURN FALSE AS predicate LIMIT 1` was evaluated than the outer `RETURN predicate LIMIT 1` cuts out nothing.
2. if also `RETURN TRUE AS predicate LIMIT 1` was evaluated - then the outer `RETURN predicate LIMIT 1` will cut out the `FALSE` row.

```
MATCH (from: FromLabel)-[:REL_LABEL]-(to: ToLabel)
CALL {
    WITH from
    CALL {
        WITH from
        MATCH (from: FromLabel)-[:OTHER_REL_LABEL]-(other: OtherLabel)
        WHERE // any following conditions you'd like or other expressions
        RETURN TRUE AS predicate LIMIT 1
     UNION
        RETURN FALSE AS predicate LIMIT 1
    }
    RETURN predicate LIMIT 1

}
RETURN from
```